# Array empty after cloning one to many relation self reference

Tags: symfony, doctrine, clone, one-to-many

I'm trying to clone an entity, having a one-to-many self-referencing in the class and the goal is to display as follows:

```
parent entity: 
 product {
    id: 34
    parent_product_id: null
    clone_products_id: [12,45,24] 
 }

child clone entity:
 product {
    id: null
    parent_product_id: 34
    clone_products_id: null
 }
```

I succeed cloning the entity, but in the parent the value of array clone_products_id is always null, and can't figure out why. My entity code:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="parentProduct", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $clonedProduct;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="clonedProduct", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_product_id",referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $parentProduct;

public function __construct(){
    $this->clonedProduct = new \ArrayCollection();
}

//getting the ids of the clones
/*
* @Groups({"product"})
*/
public function getClonedProductIds(){

  $clones = $this->getClonedProduct();
  $idsClone = new \ArrayCollection();
  foreach ($clones as $item) {
    $id = $item->getId();
    $idsClone->add($id);
  }

  return $idsClone;
}
```

and the clone function:

```
public function clone(Product $product){

    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

    $clonedProduct = clone $product;
    $clonedProduct->setParentProduct($product);

    $em->persist($clonedProduct);
    $em->flush();

    return $clonedProduct;
}
```

and the main function that calls our clone function:

```
public function productAction(){

   $clonedProduct = $productRepo()->clone($product);
   return $this->json($clonedProduct, Response::HTTP_OK, [],
      ['groups' => ['product']]);
}
```

So the only problem is that the ids of the clones aren't in the clonedProduct array. Any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, 
I created the method:

```
public function addToArray($product)
{ 
   this->clonedProduct[] = $product;
   return $this;
}
```